# How can I alias a pytest fixture?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a few pytest fixtures I use from third-party libraries and sometimes their names are overly long and cumbersome. Is there a way to create a short alias for them?

**For example**: the `django_assert_max_num_queries` fixture from [pytest-django](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#django_assert_max_num_queries). I would like to call this `max_queries` in my tests.

Comment: Just write a fixture that returns that fixture, e.g. `@pytest.fixture def short_name(long_name): yield long_name`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I tried the same thing but with `return` instead of `yield`. I didn't think to make it a generator.

Comment: @mrbean-bremen please make an answer out of your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot just add an alias in the form of

```py
max_queries = django_assert_max_num_queries
```

because fixtures are looked up by name at run-time and not imported (and even if they can be imported in some cases, this is not recommended).

But you can always write your own fixture that just yields another fixture:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def max_queries(django_assert_max_num_queries):
    yield django_assert_max_num_queries
```

Done this way, `max_queries` will behave exactly the same as `django_assert_max_num_queries`.
Note that you should use `yield` and not `return`, to make sure that the control is returned to the fixture.